# 555 astable operation not getting stable frequency

Tags: 555

I needed a 38 kHz wave no matter the shape. So I started off with a 555 timer to produce a 38 kHz rectangular wave using its astable mode. Here's the circuit:
[image]

For that I used R1=9.8kohm, R2=17.6kohm, and C=820pF. At the beginning, the frequency I measured was right at 38.2 kHz but as time passes by the output frequency started scaling up for as much as 2 kHz. I mean, the frequency increased by 2 kHz in less than half an hour. I tried to change the type of the capacitor just to make sure that the capacitor was ok. But I didn't get a constant freq. either. Maybe it's with 555 timer that makes it behave like that?

Comment: Have you checked that no components are getting hot? Are you sure that your frequency meter is stable? Is Vcc stable?

Comment: No, nothing getting hot. I measure the frequency using my 1054Z scope. So nothing wrong with that. Also I checked Vcc. It's completely stable.

Comment: Also I double checked the frequency using my digital multimeter I got nearly same result

Comment: Are you using an anti-static mat to run your circuit on? Do you have another 555 to hand to try?

Comment: Idea: Use your sound card to produce a 8.5 kHz tone. AC-couple into diode, leads to 19 kHz-periodic signal. AC-couple into diode, leads to 38 kHz-periodic signal. tadaaa!

Comment: @AndrewMorton I replaced it with a new timer. I got exactly the same result. It was at 40 kHz when I took it out. With the new timer I got the same 40 kHz! Seems that the problem is not with timer itself

Comment: @dirac16 power supply? I don't even know – most capacitors are rated for 20%, 10% or, best-case, 5% tolerance. 2 kHz of 40 kHz error is actually 5% – so I'd simply say, "your circuit is operating within the expected accuracy. Move on."

Comment: @MarcusMüller nice idea. But I want it outdoor. I want to modulate an IR LED. So it's for communication purposes. I can't use it there!

Comment: @dirac16 ... that is a **crucial** information. I added it to the question.

Comment: @dirac 16 Do you have a decoupling capacitor directly between the power and ground pins of the 555.  .1-.01uF should do.

Comment: @RoyC I used a .1uF tantalum capacitor to bypass the power supply noise. Today when I changed the polarity of the cap I got a pretty much accurate result. This is because at the time of setting things up I couldn't make a difference between its positive and negative leads so I went with a configuration and took it for granted. I should have checked it back to make sure it wasn't with that. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an oscillator for communication purposes, C-charge based oscillators won't do – aside from a very few speciality devices, capacitors are rated for 5%, 10% or even 20% tolerance. So I'd say your circuit operates well within the physical boundaries of what your components offer.

I'd strongly recommend just getting something that has a trimmed internal oscillator – that something might actually be an 38 kHz oscillator, or, even simpler, a microcontroller generating 38 kHz with e.g. a PWM unit. This option sounds twice as reasonable considering that when communicating over IR, you most probably already have some digital logic!

Comment: even though it may have some tolerance the capacitance should not change. But why does the frequency keep jumping up and down? The inly thing that can change the frequency in my circuit is the capacitance. Do you mean its capacitance changes a little bit during operation?

Comment: Probably, or your resistors heat up, or, also possible, the silicon die heats up and changes the characteristics

Comment: No, nothing has got hot yet. I just replaced the cap with a tantalum one. I see the same thing. It increased by 1 Hz in less than 5 mins. Quite strange

Comment: 1 Hz is an accuracy of 25ppm. That's what a **good** quartz-based oscillator achieves. Really, settle your expectations.

Comment: I want to let the circuit be on till tomorrow. Then I will check to see where it gets to. I don't expect it to go far beyond 42 kHz.

Comment: @dirac16 another reason might really be the stability of your power source.

Answer (score 0):

May be a shot in the dark, but could this be due to dc bias on the capacitor lowering its capacitance?  You say you tried changing the type of the capacitor.  Did you change it something other than ceramic - such as a film capacitor, which experiences less effect from dc bias?

Comment: NP0/C0G ceramic capacitors are often good choices for your amount of capacitance as well, and are often rock solid.  If you're using a Y5U dielectric capacitor the dc bias effect is more likely.

Comment: I am using a ceramic cap. I don't have a film cap in my stock. Instead, I used a 1 uF Tantalum cap just to observe that how it would behave. Does it have any advantage over the ceramic cap?

Comment: Tantalums shouldn't have any dc bias effect.  If you saw a similar increase in frequency over time with the tantalum as the capacitor, then dc bias is unlikely to be the issue.